# Request not taking Dynamic User Defined cookie data from cookie manager

Tags: magento, jmeter, cookiemanager

I have added form_Key from Magento base URL as user defined cookie and the same is not getting passed as cookie in subsequent requests.

Name      Value                 Domain                   Path
form_key  ${Crr_LaunchFormKey}  xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.com  customer/account/login/

In Results tree request data says [No Cookies]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epeBh.png)

Answer (score 0):

"The same" is not getting passed as cookie in subsequent requests because the path is not "the same"

If the path is not "the same" - JMeter doesn't pass "the same" to the subsequent request.

Correct path to be "the same" and JMeter will start passing "the same" to the subsequent requests.

[image]

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265)
- [Using HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)